# What are the empty single quotes for after rescue?

Tags: ruby, exception, single-quotes, rescue

```
 while t = Integer(gets.chomp) rescue ''
   if t.is_a? Integer
    break
   else
    print "Please enter a whole number "
   end
  end
```

I'm just trying to figure out exactly why I need those empty single quotes after rescue for this loop to work.

Answer (score 0):

because Integer(gets.chomp) can raise an exception, which caught by rescue and assign to `t` value as empty string

Answer (score 0):

This is referred to as an inline `rescue`. If `t = Integer(gets.chomp)` raises any exception inheriting from `StandardError` it will be rescued and an empty string will be returned instead. You can think of it like this:

```
begin
  do_something
rescue
  ''
end
```

The problem with this approach is that you can't specify exception classes to rescue from, so you may accidentally mask errors that you didn't expect, like a `NoMethodError` raised when misspelling the `chomp` method:

```
Integer(gets.chmp) rescue ''
#=> ""
```